# Trying to access a global variable from class instance in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to access a global variable which was defined in my main Python file from inside an object instance. I have read some other questions on the topic and I learned I need to use the `global` keyword inside my class method first.

However, even so, my code does not seem to work:

```
from secondclass import SecondClass

somelist = [1,2,3]
obj = SecondClass()

obj.mainmethod()
```

And here is my other file containing `secondclass`:

```
class SecondClass():
  
  def mainmethod(self):
    global somelist
    print (somelist)
```

Even through I am using the global keyword, Python still gives me error:

```
NameError: name 'somelist' is not defined
```

Why is that?

Comment: In Python, `global` is local to the module.  It is not global worldwide.  If your class needs that list, then you should pass it to the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`global` is scoped to the same module.

You have multiple options to solve this, among them:

- Pass the variable to the class and use `self.attribute`.
- Pass the variable to the method.
- Create a module holding the global, such as `globals.py` and import it from both sides.
- Inject the global using `import secondclass; secondclass.somelist = [1,2,3]`

And plenty of other solutions.

Personally, I'd go for the first or second any day of the week.